# Values not being inserted into the right record/s MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When inserting a value into a table, instead of just assigning the value to the single record it is assigning it to all of them:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user
(
    userID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    userName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,        
    PRIMARY KEY (userID)
);
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rewards
(
    rewardID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    rewardDescription VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (rewardID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS promos
(   
    issueDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    expiryDateOfReward DATETIME GENERATED ALWAYS AS(issueDate + INTERVAL 6 MONTH),  
    quantity BIT DEFAULT 0,
    userID VARCHAR(50) REFERENCES user(userID),
    rewardID VARCHAR(5) REFERENCES rewards(rewardsID),
    PRIMARY KEY(userID, rewardID)
);

    INSERT INTO user
    VALUES('DV2015', 'Bob'),
          ('DV2016', 'Mary'),
          ('DV2017', 'Megan');

INSERT INTO rewards
VALUES('rw10', '10% Off'),
      ('rw20', '20% Off'),
      ('rw30', '30% Off');

INSERT INTO promos (issueDate, quantity, userID, rewardID)
            VALUES(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DV2016', 'rw10'),
                  (DEFAULT, 1, 'DV2015', 'rw20'),
                  (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'DV2017', 'rw30');
```

I am then selecting it:

```
SELECT userName, 
       rewards.rewardID, 
       rewards.rewardDescription, 
       promos.quantity 
  FROM user
  JOIN promos
    ON user.userID = promos.userID
  JOIN rewards
    ON promos.rewardID = promos.rewardID
 WHERE user.userID = 'DV2015';
```

I don't know if the error is in the creation of the tables, me inserting records, or in the select statement.
This is how it outputs:

[image]

I only want Bob with a userID of 'DV2015' to have a 'quantity' of 1 on 'rw20'. rw10 and rw30 must still have a quantity of 0. However when inserting data it is giving him all the rewards

Comment: sorry about that i forgot to remove the other insert values

Comment: i removed those extra entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an accidental cross join here:

```
JOIN rewards
    ON promos.rewardID = promos.rewardID
```

Which is of course true for all promos records. You probably meant:

```
JOIN rewards
    ON rewards.rewardID = promos.rewardID
```

If you want "rw10 and rw30 must still have a quantity of 0" you should switch to `LEFT JOIN` rather than `(INNER) JOIN`.

Comment: If you change the condition to  `ON rewards.rewardID = promos.rewardID` will only return a record (even if you use outer join) you need to use `CROSS JOIN` on `user` and `rewards` table. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e85e5/1 @GeneSmith

Answer (score 1):

Join from the promos table instead

```
SELECT u.userName, 
   r.rewardID, 
   r.rewardDescription, 
   p.quantity 
FROM promos p
JOIN user u ON u.userID = p.userID
JOIN rewards r ON r.rewardID = p.rewardID
WHERE u.userID = 'DV2015';
```

Answer (score 0):

you did mistake to insert data into table

```
insert into table_name values()//if you provide values all the column
```

otherwise

```
insert into table_name (col1,col2...coln) values('use1','use2'....n)
```

so in your case in user table value will be insert like below

```
INSERT INTO user values(1,'user_name1'),(2,'user_name2');
```

Other two tables (rewards,promos) data insertion process is valid

Answer (score 0):

From your expect result you can try this.

`CROSS JOIN` by `user` and `rewards` tables to descartes products result.

Then `promos` tables `OUTER JOIN` base on `CROSS JOIN` result set.

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    userID VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    userName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL  
);
CREATE TABLE  rewards
(
    rewardID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    rewardDescription VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE promos
(   
    issueDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    expiryDateOfReward DATETIME ,  
    quantity int DEFAULT 0,
    userID VARCHAR(50),
    rewardID VARCHAR(5)
);

    INSERT INTO user
    VALUES('DV2015', 'Bob'),
          ('DV2016', 'Mary'),
          ('DV2017', 'Megan');

INSERT INTO rewards
VALUES('rw10', '10% Off'),
      ('rw20', '20% Off'),
      ('rw30', '30% Off');

INSERT INTO promos (issueDate, quantity, userID, rewardID)
            VALUES(0, 0, 'DV2016', 'rw10'),
                  (0, 1, 'DV2015', 'rw20'),
                  (0, 0, 'DV2017', 'rw30');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT userName, 
       r.rewardID, 
       r.rewardDescription, 
       coalesce(p.quantity,0) quantity
  FROM user u CROSS JOIN rewards r
  LEFT JOIN promos p
    ON u.userID = p.userID and r.rewardID = p.rewardID
 WHERE u.userID = 'DV2015'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e85e5/13/0)**:

```
| userName | rewardID | rewardDescription | quantity |
|----------|----------|-------------------|----------|
|      Bob |     rw20 |           20% Off |        1 |
|      Bob |     rw10 |           10% Off |        0 |
|      Bob |     rw30 |           30% Off |        0 |
```